# Is there any performance benefit if we exclude null rows in where clause in Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

Table `Foo` structure:

```
ID – PK
SampleCol – Can have null and is not indexed
SampleCol2, SampleCol3, etc
```

Table `Foo` has some 100,000+ rows with many `SampleCol` as `NULL`.

SQL query #1:

```
select * 
from Foo 
where SampleCol = 'Test'
```

SQL query #2:

```
select * 
from Foo 
where SampleCol is not null and SampleCol = 'Test'
```

Does query #2 have any performance benefit over query #1? Or any suggestions on how to improve performance of these SQL queries?

Thanks!

Comment: Its depends on your database structure. Have a look at the execution plan and see. And if you are looking for performance assistance you need to use "Paste The Plan" to make the execution plan available to us.

Comment: No, there is no performance improvement in query 2. Index the column!

Comment: @DaleK, I saw the execution plan and didn't find any difference, hence, the question for any expert tips. Plus I have provided a sample ds, not sure what additional ds information would be required as it was more of a theoretic question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks @juergend, I found the same results using execution plan, will close the question, thanks for your time.

Comment: The predicate `SampleCol = 'Test'` implies NOT NULL. Adding the other predicate doesn't help the optimizer. As mentioned by Juergen, without index, you will get a full table scan (or clustered index scan) for this query anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not help -- although it could make things slightly (probably unmeasurably) worse.

The condition `SampleCol = 'Test'` is exactly the comparison you want to make.  So, the database has to make this comparison, in some fashion, for every row that is returned.

There are basically two situations.  Without an index, your query needs to do a full table scan.  Two comparisons on each row (one for `NULL` and one for the value) take longer than a single comparison.  To be honest, some databases *might* optimize this just to the equality comparison, so the two could be equal.  I don't think SQL Server does this elimination but it might.

With an index, SQL Server will use an index for the `=` comparison.  It might then do an additional comparison against `NULL` (even though that is redundant).  You run into a bigger issue here, though:  The more complicated the predicate the more likely the optimizer gets confused and doesn't use an index.

There is a third case where your column is used for partitioning.  I do not know if the redundant comparison would have an impact on partition pruning.

You want your `where` comparisons to be simple.  In general, you want to let the optimizer do its work.  On very rare occasions, you might want to give the optimizer some help, but that is very, very, very rare -- and generally involves functions that are much more expensive to run than simple comparisons.